# What's the best practices to handle frequently changing timezones

Tags: java, time, timezone, jodatime

I'm writing a toy logistics service. As a result, products will travel through lots of different timezones, and I'll need to query both the strict ordering of events, as well as what hour of day it is for products (for example, what happened when the sun was at its hottest, at 1200).

At the moment, I'm saving jodatime DateTimes and trying to deal with them exclusively, but I know time is mighty tricky, and I'm wondering if I need to do anything else to make sure it all works.

Comment: Store it in UTC time only?

Comment: Then I can't query for things like the middle of the day

Comment: Yes, but the concept of the middle of the day itself is probably the wrong one: there can be more than one middle of the day per day when you travel. Note that the closer you are to the poles, the slower you have to travel for such effects. By the way: the middle of whichday: consider traveling at the date boundary. You can travel such that after 2 hours after lunch of today is one hour before lunch of yesterday... I would use UTC, and fire an updateTimezone event whenever crossing a timezone. ..

Comment: That's a pretty good point. I would want the middle of the day on different days - I'm directly interested in the hottest and coldest parts of the days. Firing the updateEvent is a pretty good way to keep track of the exact set of events as they happened, and it helps manage the complexity of moving over the date line.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're recording events as they occur (rather than planning for future events), you probably don't need to worry about changes to time zone rules which occur in the future.

As such, it would be reasonable to store a timestamp (e.g. as UTC) and also the time zone ID for the location of the event. To make querying easier, you *could* also store the local time at the time of the event. Just be aware that as a toy is travelling through time zones, there could be multiple events at different instants in time, all of which occur at "midday" on the same day (but in different zones). You really need to think carefully about what queries you really want to perform on the local date/time values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with jodatime but when I need to store the time I always enjoy using Epoch time because it is very easy to manipulate to get different formats. If you're interested in it here is a converter website that I find very helpful: http://www.epochconverter.com/